# What would happen if a Time Machine backup over Wi-Fi is in progress and I remove my laptop?

Tags: backup, time-machine, airport, time-capsule

I just purchased an AirPort Time Capsule and set up backups of my OS X Sierra. (Actually, they're going to a USB drive connected to it but I think it amounts to the same thing.)

If leave for work with my laptop in the middle of a backup, will Time Machine handle that gracefully and do something sane or will it have a meltdown and corrupt the backup and all the other backups and become unusable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time Machine should handle this gracefully, with the in-progress backup continuing the next time you connect.

I have many many Time Machine backups that have all been done over wifi, and I have honestly paid no attention to whether or not backups are in progress or complete while taking my laptop in and out of the house.

Answer (score 2):

Time machine backs up periodically.  If you interrupt a backup (say your computer leaves the network during a backup) it will not complete, but your previous backups should remain in tact and it will resume the schedule when you are back.  You can go into **enter time machine** and familiarize yourself with how it backs up over time.